# When i set an UIButton's title, it just can't work by 'UIButton.setTitle()'

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm doing some simple coding about swift. The problem is , I have 16 UIButtons, they are all the same. In a for loop, I give all the buttons which are faced up a emoji title. But it just can't work. And in the end, only one button can show the emoji. But in the console, they can all print the correct title! Why?

```swift
@IBOutlet var cardButtons: [UIButton]!

func updateViewFromModel(){
        for index in cardButtons.indices{
            let button = cardButtons[index]
            let card = game.cards[index]
            if card.isFacedUp{
                let thisEmoji = getEmoji(for: card)
                print(thisEmoji)
                button.setTitle(thisEmoji, for: .normal)
                button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }else{
                button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
                if card.isMatched{
                    button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
                }else{
                    button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var emojiChoices = ["","","","","","","","",""]

    var emoji = [Int: String]()

    func getEmoji(for card:Card) -> String{
        if emoji[card.identifier] == nil, emojiChoices.count > 0{
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(emojiChoices.count)))
            emoji[card.identifier] = emojiChoices.remove(at: randomIndex)
        }
        return emoji[card.identifier] ?? "?"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK...fine, it's a silly problem. I set the title color as white, that's why they can't show on the screen...Sorry for your watching...

Comment: You should delete your question.